# Ubuntu reinstall fails

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

So, I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 after breaking it by running:

```sh
sudo apt remove python3.8
```

I want to keep my files, so during the installation, I chose 'Something else' because I don't get the 'Reinstall Ubuntu' option.

I selected the Ubuntu partition, change, use as ext4 journaling file system, do not format, mount point /

After that, I get asked to choose an EFI partition for the Grub.

At the end of the installation, I get a fatal error about how Grub failed to install.

I tried running Boot-Repair, but nothing changed.

What am I supposed to do?
I also have a Windows partition in case that could help.

Comment: Try reinstalling again, formatting the partition.

Comment: But that's going to delete all my files. And I don't want that.

Comment: @AidenFive then make a backup of the files first ...

Comment: I formatted the partition, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you boot Ubuntu live USB as UEFI and not as BIOS?

Comment: yes, I did boot the USB as UEFI

Comment: were there any more details in the "grub failed to install" error?

Comment: Nope, it would only say fatal error and the installer would end. It says: Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

Is there enough space in your `EFI System partition` to install `Grub2`? If not you can install `Grub2Win` in `Windows` and make this the default bootloader. ( Some hardcore Linux users will hate me for this solution. But if it gets you booting `Ubuntu` I see it as a solution to the problem. )

Comment: There is enough space in my EFI System partition. I even deleted the partition and created a new one. When it comes to installing `Grub2Win`, I can't access my windows partition because it is also broken :/

Comment: Can you make a usb-stick with Ikki Boot.iso ( 2,6 GB ) or Super_Grub2_disk_hybrid iso ( 20 Mb )? Of course Ikki Boot has more options ( larger size of the iso ).  Both of them can boot all bootable systems on your computer.  You need another stick than the one you are booting your live environment from, but from there you can make the other stick.